# How to choose (not upload) file from server in admin (Django)

Tags: django, upload

I need to display icon(representing the type of the document inside the post) along with each post. There are hundreds of posts each year. There are about a dozen types of documents hence I need that much icons. The problem is that if I use `models.ImageField` it will upload a new image each time a post is created, and I will end up with bunch of same icons pretty soon.
So I am wondering how to implement the following logic:

1. preview_icon -> choose from server
2. upload_icon -> If the wanted icon does not exists on the server then upload and choose it from server via preview_icon field.

My initial idea is to make a new model:

```
 class PostIcon(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="icons")
        post_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"path")
```

So you can connect icon to post. But I am wondering if there is a way to implement the first logic I mentioned, because it would be much neater. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way, it's working fine. But I would love to see the solution where you can browse the server for the image rather than selecting it by `icon_name`, in this case. Hope this helps if someone has the similar issue.

```
class PostIcon(models.Model):
    icon_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    preview_icon = models.ImageField(default="path")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.icon_name)


class Post(models.Model):
    preview_icon = models.ForeignKey(PostIcon, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, related_name="post_icon")
    ...
```